# How do I test the results of an operation for a value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula

Techies--
In a nutshell, I have a condition where if I encounter a negative value after operating against other cells, I want to zero out that cell and operate against another set of cells. This formula does not work, but here is what the intent is:

```
=IF((H3+((D4+D5+D6)*-1)) < 0;M6=0;N6=C4+C5+C6 + (D6)*-1 )
```

If I add d4-d6 multiplied by -1, this gives me  a credit against a debit value I have in H3. Whenever this value exceeds the positive value of the debit in H3, I want zero out the cell (M6) and in the cell next to it (N6), I want to add another set of debits and subtract out the credit I found in D6.

Does anyone know how to do this, or something similar in EXCEL 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cell `M6` You should have this

```
=IF((H3+((D4+D5+D6)-1))<0, 0, "")
```

In Cell `N6` You should have this

```
=IF(NOT(M6 = 0), C4+C5+C6 + (D6)-1, "")
```

Comment: Should note that you can't assign a value to a cell via a formula from another cell.

Comment: @Yograj Brilliantly done! Thanks so much. BTW, what does the "" do at the end?

Comment: @Portland Runner, thanks for the info about value assignments.

Comment: @plditallo you can also simplify the formula: `=IF(H3+D4+D5+D6-1<0;0;"")` and `=IF(M6<>0;C4+C5+C6+D6-1;"")` work just as well.

Comment: `""` just set the value of the cell to nothing if statement is false. `if<<condition>,<value if true>,<value if false>)`